# How to call method with args from inside vue.js component template?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am trying to call a function that generates a url from inside my vue.js component.  The function is `[[ generateGitUrl ]]`

I am not sure if I am going in the right direction in trying to solve this problem.  My example doesn't work because I am not passing `repo, branch, hash` to the method.  So my question is, how do I pass this data to `[[ generateGitUrl ]]` from the template in my example (if this is even possible?)?  I suspect I'm going about this completely the wrong way so open to suggestions.

vue.js component

```
Vue.component('git-refs', {
    delimiters: [ '[[', ']]' ],
    props: ['jobs'],
    template: `
    <div envVars>
      <h3>Github Links</h3>
      <table>
      <template v-for="item in jobs">
      <tr>
      <td><b>Repo</b></td>
      <td><b>Branch</b></td>
      <td><b>Ref</b></td>
      </tr>
       <tr v-for="i in item.code_checkouts">
          <td>[[ i.git_repo.name ]]</td>
          <td>[[ i.git_branch_name ]]</td>
          <td>
          <a v-bind:href='[[ generateGitUrl ]]'>
          [[ i.git_hash ]]
          </a>
          </td>
       </tr>
      </template>
      </table>
    </div>
    `,
    methods: {
        generateGitUrl: function(repo, branch, hash) {
            repo = repo.split(":")[1];
            newUrl = branch+'/'+repo+hash
            return 'github.corp.test.com/' + newUrl 
        }
    },
});
```

example data:

```
repo: 'git@github.corp.test.com:team/jenkins.git'
hash: '43tsf454w3jg390t3fi'
branch: 'feature/newfeature'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call with parens like any function, e.g. `<a :href="getURL(arg1, arg2)">click me</a>`

In your case:

`<a v-bind:href="generateGitUrl(i.git_repo.name, i.git_branch_name, i.git_hash)">`

I'm unclear if those are the right arguments for your particular case, but you get the idea.

Comment: that was infinitely easier than i thought it would be - thanks